# generate Class diagram for iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, class, uml, class-diagram

i know how to generate class diagram in Xcode for iPhone app.

but i am searching for alternate way to represent it, because my app is very much big and it will difficult to put  diagram and explanation in my thesis report.

any idea how to represent all classes or app in short manner so i can put into my thesis report.

thank you very much

Comment: "Short manner" can be very subjective. Also are you looking for a free tool/software?

Comment: like if u right click in .net and select View Class diagram its so simple to see and read and easily understandable but this is not in the case with Xcode....it create so huge class diagram which is not possible to documentation

Comment: not really tool or software i just need advice how other people do if they want to document their apps in class diagram representation

Comment: It all depends on the tool and medium you want to display the information. On the web I can generate a very large paper size. But for psychical pager you have to break it down to concrete area. For example one page would just deal with storing user settings.  And for your thesis, you will have to manually generate them yourself.

Comment: i am also thing to create it manually..thanks for advice

Answer (score 31):

Just download  [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnigraffle/) and then go to `File->Open->Select your XcodeProject file` and that's it you'll have a class diagram.

Comment: Seems to be unable to handle larger projects. "Not Responding" every time.

Comment: It crashed for me as well if I opened the XCode project directly from OmniGraffle. My project is quite big, so I guess that is the problem. But if I used https://github.com/nst/objc_dep to generate the .dot file and then open it with OmniGraffle it worked, but not for CircleGraph type.

Comment: Will not work for swift, me too looking for alternative solution., if any one find please let us all know. Thanks

Comment: Yes, It won't work for Swift, I am also searching for similar tool, will inform if found some reliable tool.

Comment: This link is invalid but I searched OmniGraffle 7 in mac's app store and I got that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Omnigraffle to generate UML diagrams directly from Xcode.

Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081435/41116).

Answer (score 1):

Select the "**FirstDemo.xcdatamodeld**".Goto the  "File" select the "print" option save as pdf formate in "ERD diagram".

Any screen issue faced  goto the "File" select the "Page Setup"manage the custom sizes.

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby script created by 'yoshimkd' that scans all swift code from the specified folders and files and automatically generates an entity diagram (similar to a class diagram) which can be viewed in a browser.

Usage:
https://martinmitrevski.com/2016/10/12/swift-class-diagrams-and-more/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

OmniGraffle only works with projects that have an Objective-C hierarchy! Do not waste time trying this for Swift!

Edit: I ended up using LucidChart instead. Their trial version was good enough for writing my class diagram
https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/

Comment: This is already mentioned in the comments to the highest-voted answer. However, if you are able to add additional details, this answer could meaningfully stand on its own.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/).

Comment: From the website: "StarUML is an open source project to develop fast, flexible, extensible, featureful, and freely-available UML/MDA platform _running on Win32 platform_" (emphasis mine). How would this work for a project running on a Mac?