# How can I generate UML diagrams from Xcode4

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, uml, xcode3to4

I watched a video with xcode 3, that shows a button "Design" that displays a UML diagram, but I can't find how to do it with xcode 4.

Comment: would be very interested if something like this existed!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) This has templates for UML diagrams.

If you drop an Xcode4 project file onto its dock icon, it will generate a UML diagram from that.

What it doesn't do is generate code from diagrams.

Comment: Very neat. One annoying thing though - if you create methods/instance variables via @property's (I used Xcode4.6.1) it won't list them - even if you have methods and instance variables ticked in the import dialog.

Comment: Omnigraffle understands only Objective-C files, how about C++?

Comment: Without properties being recognized, it's a pretty useless UML diagram .

Comment: Don't forget to mention the $99 price tag as a big disadvantage of OmniGraffle.

Comment: crashed with multiple target x code project open with xcode 7.0

Answer (score 3):

Search for "Xcode Design Tools" in Help.  That will show you a tutorial that will walk you through creating a diagram.

EDIT >>>

It looks like the instructions are actually for XCode 3 and that UML Modeling was removed from XCode 4.  The only modeling I could find in XCode 4 is Data Modeling: File>New>New File...  and then look under 'Core Data'.

[Class Modeling alternatives for Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061583/class-modeling-alternatives-for-objective-c)

You might also want to check out [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: i don't found it but i will surch in google , but it's possible ? to show diagram from an existing code ?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Paradigm can generate uml from objective c and back (haven't tried it yet, can't tell how well it does the job).

Comment: https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/276/277/7284_reverseengin.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use yEd ... not the best solution and does not generate graphs as OmniGraffle can do but at least it can export in SVG and use GraphML files to store the data. (and it is fee)

http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_helpresources.html

Answer (score 1):

This may help you but I didn't personally tested,

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XCodeDesignTools/XCodeDesignTools.pdf

> The Xcode class modeling tool helps you to explore and understand the classes in your project, whether they’re written in Objective-C, C++, Java, or a mixture of those languages. It allows you to see class relationships (subclass and superclass relationships—including support for multiple inheritance in C++), protocols (or interfaces in Java), and categories. In the diagram view, color and text coding help you to quickly distinguish between classes, categories, and protocols, and between project and framework code. The visibility (public, private, protected) of member functions and variables is shown appropriately. (If you are not familiar with any of these terms, you should consult suitable programming texts.)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The link responds with 404 and I wonder if this tool is still available in Xcode 10? I would really appreciate it, yet I cannot find it anymore

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for a quick fix to the same problem as the OP here, but the solution that helped me most - generate a diagram from my existing XCode project that will show the operations in every class I select - was to use my still existing installation of XCode 3.

Remarks:
1. It's not real UML but it's still good to get/keep an overview.
2. You can export a diagram to PDF using the print-to-PDF feature available in most Mac OS X applications.
3. If you upgraded from XCode 3.2.6 to 4.x by upgrading Snow Leopard to Lion like me, you'll find your XCode 3 installation at /Developer-3.2.6/Applications/Xcode.app.