# Will my Xcode 4 project work in Xcode 3?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, uml, class-diagram, xcode3to4

Further to this question:

> [Make UML with the code in xcode4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079312/make-uml-with-the-code-in-xcode4)

I wrote some code with Xcode 4. The UML modelling feature in Xcode 3 was removed in Xcode 4.

I would still like to use the UML modelling feature in Xcode 3, will my project written with Xcode 4 work in Xcode 3,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make UML with the code in xcode4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079312/make-uml-with-the-code-in-xcode4). Please don't double-post.

Comment: ok sorry i will not do it again

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your diagrams, but your Xcode 4 project will (mostly) work with Xcode 3. (At least, it ought to work well enough to generate diagrams based on the classes.)

Comment: Similarly, I can't comment on the diagrams but after I upgraded a project to use with Xcode 4 it started crashing every time I opened it after a couple of launches. I then opened the same project in Xcode 3 and had no problems at all.

Comment: @LaceySnr i can't do it with the core data modeling or something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you’d like to continue using Xcode 4 for development and you have access to another computer or a VMWare image, you could install a copy of Xcode 3 on it and use it to generate diagrams only.

Alternatively, you get a commercial product like [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/276/277/7284_reverseengin.html) to reverse engineer your Objective-C source code or start using Xcode 3 again for development (if possible).

Comment: @Mehdi You can have 3 and 4 installed side-by-side. Just install 3 to a folder other than `/Developer`, like `/xcode3`.

Comment: @cajunluke that’s good know. @mehdi looks like side-by-side is the best alternative