# Generate class diagram using xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uml

I have created a iOS project and want to create class diagram. And before that manually I just wanted to know if there are any UML class diagram generator tool for xcode or any other tool that generates the class diagram using the xcode project.

Thanks

Comment: I understand that there are other tools like **Omni Graffle** that generates the class diagram using the xcode project, But I was looking for a tool that can be integrated with xcode and then generate class diagram. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[OmniGraffle](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/omnigraffle-6/id711830901?mt=12) is the right tool that exactly matches your need. I have used it a couple of times for generating class diagrams from Xcode projects(using the .xcodeproj file) but I had to do few changes since my design was not top notch then but if the classes are perfectly designed you can get the best out of this tool. Its not free but you get a 30 day trial and after installing go to

```
 File->Open->Browse and select your .xcodeproj file.
```

Possible duplicate [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857429/generate-class-diagram-for-iphone-app)

Comment: i can't able to drag or open my xcode file into OmniGraffle. what's the issue with me?

Comment: @Question Did you try to browse your .xcodeproj, check the version compatibility of OmniGraffle and Xcode.

Comment: I tried with 6.0 and 6.0.4 is it possible in this versions?

Comment: Not working for Swift

Comment: I have it working fine with Swift, but it doesn't generate a true class diagram... Looks more like a file overview.

Comment: @NikMos I have not tested this with Swift still, I had it working during my objective C days.